# how can i send successful ping to one file and email log of failed ping using blat and nncron

Tags: batch-file, cron, blat

I am able to send body of text with blat and also schedule task with nncron to send at specified time.

Now I want to echo the failure of the ping to another file and send it using email via blat.
something like this:

```
ping -n 4 %%a| findstr "TTL=">>%log% || (
<<want to write to unreachables log here>>
Blat body.txt -i "on behalf of name" -to name@domain -attach %hosts% -attach %unreachables%
)
```

Please let me know how I can write to the other file then email it.

Comment: What do you want to write to the unreachables log?

Comment: i would like to write the failure of the ping there and email it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ping -n 4 %%a| findstr "TTL=">>%log% || (
echo ping to %%a failed >>%unreachables%
Blat body.txt -i "on behalf of name" -to name@domain -attach %hosts% -attach %unreachables%
)
```

should yield a message to the file whose name is in `unreachables`